# Run time Error '13' Type Mismatched on using .Find Function in Userform

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CBu_Login_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lrow As Long, find_value As String
Dim cel As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserName")
lrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow)
find_value = Me.TB_Username.Value
Set cel = rng.Find(What:=find_value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not cel Is Nothing Then
    If Me.TB_Password.Value = cel.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        UF_Encoding.L_User.Caption = "Welcome " & cel.Offset(0, 2).Value & "!" & " You are logged in."
        UF_Encoding.TB_Operator.Text = cel.Offset(0, 2).Value
        UF_Encoding.Show
        Me.Hide
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Username/Password"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Username/Password"
End If

End Sub
```

This code is giving me a `Type Mismatched` error on the `.Find` part.
The code is in a `Command Button`.
Also, this works sometimes and then suddenly will throw up the `Mismatched Error`.
Please help why it is throwing the error and how to correct it.
I don't want to resort to looping since i have many users.

Comment: What happens when you change `After:=ActiveCell` to `After:=ws.Range("A2")`?

Comment: wow, i must be dozing off to must have missed this. Haha thanks sid.

Comment: Bookmark [THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) `FOREVER` or till the time you no longer deviate from that.

Comment: believe me i did bookmark that. all of my codes adapted to that. It's funny that i fail to notice the activecell. haha i guess a cup of coffee would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid the use of `ActiveCell`, unless there's an absolutely necessary reason to incorporate it.

Please see [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Simply change

```
After:=ActiveCell
```

to

```
After:=ws.Range("A2")
```

Comment: `Errors with .Find are usually because LookIn is set wrongly.` I hate to say that but your assumptions are incorrect :)

Comment: Hello, Sid! :) Hmm. I'm actually reading up on it now. I checked the MSDN database and it seems `LookIn` is more than I thought it was (did not know it even takes a Variant, haha). However, whenever I personally encounter this with a find, I usually remove `LookIn` and it works again. Feel free to correct my code above though. ;)

Comment: setting `Activecell` to `ws.Range("A2")` solved the trick. `Me.TB_Username.Value` is a string. `xlFormulas` worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, though Sid deserves more of a credit here since his comment alone solved everything. :D

Comment: + 1 `Feel free to correct my code above though. ;) – BK201 2 mins ago` I just did :)

Comment: @BK201 i accepted it because your previous answer works although your presumption was incorrect. :) and sid commented it out so i can't do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution. I've commented everything, so that you can follow the specific steps.

```
Sub Hide_Me()

    Dim rngHeadings As Range 'the range where your headings are
    Dim arrHideColumns() As Variant 'the array, where you list all headings that should be hidden
    Dim Item As Variant 'a common variable for the for-each-loop
    Dim rngResult As Range 'the range for the search result
    
'Assign the range, where your headings are

    Set rngHeadings = Worksheet1.Range("C3:E3")

'List the headings you want to be hidden

    arrHideColumns = Array("Address", "Phone Number")

'Loop through your list

    For Each Item In arrHideColumns
    
'Use the .FIND method of the range-object
'Please read more about this method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

        Set rngResult = rngHeadings.Find(Item)

'If there is a result

        If Not rngResult Is Nothing Then

'Hide the column

            rngResult.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```